# E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

My App works ok but I have the next error:

**Code**

```
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1290569648
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-02 05:21:22.915        49-49/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is like mine, you forgot `setEGLContextClientVersion(2);` when setting up your glSurfaceView